# Shutting down NAS and Windows 8 PC from UPS

Tags: networking, windows-8, shutdown, nas

I have a Synology DS415+ NAS. I am planning to buy a UPS for it, probably an Eaton 5S1600.

I want the UPS to shutdown the NAS automatically, which I believe it can via its USB port.

I would also like my PC to shutdown.

I know the NAS can run as a UPS server. I have seen instructions for using WinNUT as a UPS client to receive a network signal from the UPS Server on the NAS. WinNUT appears to have only been maintained up to Windows 7.

Is what I'm proposing possible and is there an easier way to achieve it?

(I know I could 'just try it', but I'd rather have a plan before I invest in hardware.)

Comment: What about a UPS like [this](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16842102214)? It has the USB Interface, and 3 outlets that switch off when it detects that your computer is turned off or put into sleep mode (read the overview section).  Is that what you are looking for?  You could plug the NAS into an eco outlet, and when your computer turns off, it will turn everything in the eco outlets off as well.  The only downside is if your NAS isn't close enough to your computer and UPS, it will be hard to have this kind of setup.

Comment: Thanks @TimmyJim, but wouldn't that just crash the NAS with a power failure, rather than shutting it down?

Comment: How do you properly shut down your NAS? Via the computeramp? I've never used a NAS so I am not so familiar with them.

Comment: @TimmyJim you usually shut it down in a similar way to shutting down a computer. It also has software that monitors a USB port that allows it to be shutdown by the UPS. The UPS has a special USB port that signals to the NAS (or any other device connected) that it should shutdown. The NAS then shuts down cleanly. If you just switch off the power it's like shutting down a PC by switching off the power, you risk data corruption as files may not have been fully written to disk, etc.